# Is this PPA safe and will it work?

Tags: 12.04, unity, ppa, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anton0/unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

# Reboot

gconftool-2 -s --type boolean /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/menu_always_visible true
```

It's supposed to stop the global menu from fading away however I've never seen anyone use such a thing before so I don't know if it's even possible or if this is fake or something.

Comment: Can you share with us where/how you found this PPA?

Comment: It was posted on ubuntuforums.org

and this is the ppa page:  https://launchpad.net/~anton0/+archive/unity

Answer (score 0):

That is basically the equivalent of downloading software from a website and running it on Windows, but IIUC is potentially more insecure because this new PPA could publish a newer version of a program you didn't intent to obtain from them, obsoleting a package you have and tricking your package manager into 'updating' to it. I hope someone will correct me if I'm incorrect about this.

It all comes down to this: Do you trust the source?

Comment: Update: I installed it and it works fine.